# get input file name and file extention using flask

Tags: python, flask, filenames

lets say that I have `<input name="upload" type="file">` and I am uploading `picture.jpg`. The question is how can I get the file name+extention? By other words the correct script for `request.files.filename` or `request.upload.filename`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the answer. `request.files['upload'].filename` gives the file name and extension in flask

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, if you are handling a specific extension, you may use:

```
    if extension not in file.filename:
        flash('Not suitable file !', 'danger')
        return redirect(request.url)
```

Comment: If I upload a file jpg.txt and I want to check for files with extension jpg, then this will give wrong answer